# RShiny installation ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'shiny'

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to install the Shiny package, and I am getting this error

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'httpuv' 1.4.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.4 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'shiny'
* removing 'C:/Users/ikum/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/shiny'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\ikum\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\ikum\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcbANIA/downloaded_packages/shiny_1.2.0.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status
```

Even when I try to download the latest version of `httpuv`  using the targz file, it is still going to the 1.4.1 version. I deleted `httpuv` as well and reinstalled it manually as well as from the CRAN repository. Nothing seems to be working.

I also have the latest version or RStudio and R.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Your R version is a year and a half old. I recommend updating to the latest released version of R and re-installing any packages you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to add `type = "binary"` argument:

```
install.packages("shiny", type ="binary")
```